# Is there way to change column values of selected rows through Propel?

Tags: symfony, propel

Rows are selected like that:

```
$book->getBookGenreToBooks()->???()
```

I want to change the column «checked» of all selected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given solution in your answer is very inefficient since it creates for each update a new query. A better way is to do all changes in one query:

```
BookGenreQuery::create()
    ->filterByBookId($book->getId())
    ->update(array('Checked' => 1));
```

I don't know how exactly your relations and fields are named by you should get the idea behind it.

Comment: I've found that solution before. Thanks for message.

Answer (score 0):

```
$genresToBook = $book->getBookGenreToBooks();

foreach ($genresToBook as $genreToBook) {
    $genreToBook->setChecked(1); //Set any data here
}

$genresToBook->save();
```

This isn't exactly what I want, but that works fine to me.